# Google Webmaster Tools proportional to Google exams?

Tags: google-search-console, google-workspace

I've taken no Google exams, I'm curious about apps becoming available in your Google webmasters tools and google apps the more exams you pass.  Someone I know told me that the more exams you pass, the more tools become available to you but I cannot find any information about it anywhere online.  Is this some sort of secret or am I just misinformed?

Comment: Sorry, that came off as rude and it wan't meant to.

Comment: Oh no, you're fine.  I just am constantly being told certain SEO 'things' and I'd really like to get outside opinions and knowledge since I know no other SEO people (I visit seobook and graywolf and searchengineland and seomoz and all that but i don't partcipate in any groups thus far nor have i done any google exam studying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the fetch as googlebot tool that shows you what the Googlebot see's, which is a form of scoring and bing webmaster tools has recently come up with a crawlscore metric so that could be the source of the confusion/rumors.

Comment: Perhaps.  I've seen this tool but it's available to everyone.  It doesn't actually return a numeric score, tho, right?  From what I am being told the exams, the more advanced ones, get progressivly more expensive.  Is it possible that a perk of 'spending the money' gets the successful test taker more 'stuff' (other than the obviously valuable insights into Google's ranking processes)?

Comment: @HeatherWalters I think it's unlikely, google do offer exams for Analytics, but they are pretty cheap in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: I guess I'll never know till I take a few exams myself, thanks for the 2 cents!